# i install my C# program on new computer, i install FW3.5 - and got error that need SP1?

Tags: c#, frameworks

i was install my C# program on new computer,

i install FW 3.5 - and got error that need SP1 ?

is there combined download for FrameWork 3.5 + SP1 in one File  ?

thank's in advance

Comment: The download of Framework 3.5 SP1 includes already both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en